# Reading a value from a Cascading DropDown List

Tags: javascript, php, dropdownbox

I have successfully developed a cascading dropdown list using javascript thanks to some code I found online.  The html code it generates looks as expected when I view the code inside my Firefox web developer tools.  The problem I have is that my php backend cannot read this from the $_POST buffer.  The error I get is "Undefined index".  It's almost as if the php does not see the second DDL that is dynamically added to my html page.  Is there a trick I'm missing?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var created = 0;

    function displayAccordingly() {

        if (created == 1) {
            removeDrop();
        }

        //Call mainMenu the main dropdown menu
        var mainMenu = document.getElementById('mainMenu');

        //Create the new dropdown menu
        var whereToPut = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        var newDropdown = document.createElement('select');
        newDropdown.setAttribute('id',"newDropdownMenu");
        newDropdown.setAttribute('name',"AccountNumber");
        whereToPut.appendChild(newDropdown);

        if if (mainMenu.value == "Office Expense") { //The person chose Office Expense
            var option000000000=document.createElement("option");
            option000000000.text="---";
            option000000000.value="000000000";
            newDropdown.add(option000000000,newDropdown.options[null]);

            var option160006235=document.createElement("option");
            option160006235.text="COPY PAPER AND SUPPLIES";
            option160006235.value="160006235";
            newDropdown.add(option1160006235,newDropdown.options[null]);

            var option160006237=document.createElement("option");
            option160006237.text="COPIER RENTAL AGREEMENT";
            option160006237.value="160006237";
            newDropdown.add(option1160006237,newDropdown.options[null]);

            }  else if (mainMenu.value == "Custodial") { //The person chose Custodial
            var option000000000=document.createElement("option");
            option000000000.text="---";
            newDropdown.add(option000000000,newDropdown.options[null]);

            var option164006410=document.createElement("option");
            option164006410.value="164006410";
            option164006410.text="CONTRACTED SERVICES-FACILITIES";
            newDropdown.add(option164006410,newDropdown.options[null]);

            var option164006415=document.createElement("option");
            option164006415.value="164006415";
            option164006415.text="MAINTENANCE-GROUNDS";
            newDropdown.add(option164006415,newDropdown.options[null]);

            var option164006420=document.createElement("option");
            option164006420.value="164006420";
            option164006420.text="MATERIALS AND SUPPLIES";
            newDropdown.add(option164006420,newDropdown.options[null]);
            }

        created = 1

    }

    function removeDrop() {
        var d = document.getElementById('myDiv');

        var oldmenu = document.getElementById('newDropdownMenu');

        d.removeChild(oldmenu);
    }
</script>
```

What the development tools shows as my HTML code:

[image]

My PHP Code (simplified)

```
$AccountNumber = $_POST['AcountNumber'];
```

I can read Category from the $_POST buffer, but not AccountNumber.

I am thus thinking the Javascript works fine, I don't understand why the value for AccountNumber is not placed in the $_POST buffer.

The results from a print_r($_POST) is as follows (Right after [Category] I would expect [AccountNumber]=>):
Array ( [action] => POStepTwo [logged_in_user] => 1625605397 [who] => requester [UserID] => 1625605397 [Vendor] => 2080MED [Department] => Plant [Category] => Office Expense [ShippingInstructions] => 1 [RequesterNote] => test )

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Could you add the output of `print_r($_POST);` to your question, please?

Comment: Array ( [action] => POStepTwo [logged_in_user] => 1625605397 [who] => requester [UserID] => 1625605397 [Vendor] => 2080MED [Department] => Plant [Category] => Office Expense [ShippingInstructions] => 1 [RequesterNote] => test )             Right after [Category] I would expect [AccountNumber].